# Data binding not working on React with object properties

Tags: json, reactjs, string, object

```
//I tried to render data from the nested object, but retrieve the error message
        useEffect(() => {
          axios
          .get('https://bodyshop.r2.software/wp-json/wp/v2/pages/2')
          .then(response => {
          const posts = response.data;
          const tempObj = {};
          for(let key in posts["post-meta-fields"]) {
              const modifiedKey = key.replace('_','');
              tempObj[modifiedKey] = posts["post-meta-fields"][key]
          }
          posts["post-meta-fields"] = tempObj;
                
        
          setList(posts)
          console.log(posts);
          })
        }, [])





        // nested object
        // posts = {
        // ...
        // 'post-meta-fields': {
        //   _bg_advantages_home: [''],
        //   _bg_banner_home: ['35'],
        //   _bg_info_1_home: ['41'],
        //   _bg_info_2_home: [''],
        //   _bg_offers_home: ['38'],
        //   _bg_sales_home: ['36'],
        //   _bg_video_home: ['']
        // }
        // ...
        // };

        //Example below 
        <div class="banner_title DrukFont">{posts["post-meta-fields"]["_bg_sales_home"][0]}</div>
        //meyby problem with parse incorrect parse  json method
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Main.js:46 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'title_banner_home' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

When you transforming the data you do the following:

```js
const modifiedKey = key.replace('_','');
```

which makes the underscore `_` dissapear from the front of your keys so `_bg_sales_home` will be undefined in your transformed object and accessing `[0]` on undefined will throw an error.
You have to use `bg_sales_home`:

```
<div class="banner_title DrukFont">{posts["post-meta-fields"]["bg_sales_home"][0]}</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, i forgot type  that i was trying without underscore.